# Site on the mobile has white spaces to the right

Tags: mobile, screen, space

I have redesigned a site - http://manandgiri00913109.cognizant.com.moovapp.com/. I am unable to remove the white spaces when viewing on iphone (320 px). The site fits in within the 320 px mobile screen size but has white space to the right with horizontal scroll bar activated.
I have tried out many solutions provided on the web but it didnt help my cause.